# Can I export a modification to the global namespace from my lib?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to add a method to an existing typescript type that's in the global namespace in my lib and then export it from the lib to be used by other projects. Is this possible?

Here's what I have:

*Promise.ts*

```
Promise.prototype.catchExtension = function<T>(this : Promise<T>): Promise<T> {
    return Promise.prototype.catch.apply(this, [() => { /*do stuff*/ }]);
}
```

*Promise.d.ts*

```
declare global {
    interface Promise<T> {
        catchExtension(): Promise<T>;
    }
}
export { }
```

How do I use this in another app that links to my library? I can't use `import { .... } from '@mylib'` because it was exported without a name: `export { }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around with this for a while I've found a solution. I will post it here in case it is of use to anyone else.

By putting both the declaration and definition in the .ts file and then importing the *file* (anywhere..!) in the lib my other project is then able to use the extension method as soon as it imports anything from the lib.

Here's what the final code looks like:

In the lib project:

*Promise.ts*

```
Promise.prototype.catchExtension = function<T>(this : Promise<T>): Promise<T> {
    return Promise.prototype.catch.apply(this, [() => { /*do stuff*/ }]);
}

declare global {
    interface Promise<T> {
        catchExtension(): Promise<T>;
    }
}
export { }
```

*lib.ts*

```
import './Promise'; // this can go in any file in the lib...
export { } from './Promise';
// The rest of the exports
export { Example } from './Example';
```

In the main app:

```
// Import anything from lib
import { Example } from '@mylib';

const x: Promise<string> = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => { reject(); });
x.catchExtension();
// It works! We end up in `() => { /*do stuff*/ }`
```

Answer (score 0):

try just using

```
import '@mylib'
```

It will just "run" the file, in a different scope from the module where you are importing, but it should be fine because you're modifying the global scope.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. I was able to solve the issue though.